# comparing one element text with hidden element text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to compare selected button text with answer text on click. Assume these div elements are generated dynamically.

Consider the following example of HTML snippet

```html
<div class="list-group" id="id1">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button style="display:none;"> answer </button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
<div class="list-group" id="id2">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button style="display:none;"> answer </button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
```

I tried this jQuery

```js
$("div[id^='id'] button").on('click',function(){
 
var x=$(this).parent(".list-group").find("button:last").text();
var y=$(this).text();
if(x.trim()==y.trim()){
 #dosomething
}
 else{
  #dosomething
 }


});
```

Can anybody help in this regard is much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share in OP?

Comment: please explain more

Comment: sorry, added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer would require a slight modification to your markup. Since you're really wanting the text value for the answer, I've made the 'answer' a hidden text input field (which also could help avoid bugs in your markup) instead and added an `.answer` class name. Here I can access it's value property and compare that against the answer provided from the clicked button. I have also added a `.result` class to your `p` tag.

So your markup for one question block might look like this:

```
<div class="list-group" id="id1">
   <button value="apple" >apple</button>
   <button value="orange" >orange</button>
   <button value="mandarin" >mandarin</button>
   <button value="cake">cake</button>
   <input class="answer" style="display:none;" value="cake" /> 
   <p class="result"> Result: </p>
</div>
```

Whether the answer is correct or incorrect, the `p` tag below will be updated with the result.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
     // the clicked buttons text
   let input = $(this).text();
     // the answer to this quiz block
   let answer = $(this).siblings(".answer")[0].value;
     // the result of the users attempt
   let result = input == answer;
     // if true, display 'correct!'
   result ? result = 'correct!'
     // else display 'incorrect!' 
          : result = 'incorrect!';
     // show the result to the user 
     // by selecting the .results sibling
   let display = $(this).siblings('.result')[0];
     // and updating it's innerText value. 
   display.innerText = `Result: ${result}`
});
```

A working codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/jrmclaren/pen/XqNbMY?editors=1010#0)

Good luck, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have done little bit modification. i have added HTML attribute in hidden button control with name `demo` to identify its value.

Here is my html markup.

```
<div class="list-group" id="id1">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button demo style="display:none;">text1</button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
<div class="list-group" id="id2">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button demo style="display:none;">text3</button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
<div class="list-group" id="id3">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button demo style="display:none;">text2</button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
<div class="list-group" id="id4">
  <button >text1</button>
  <button >text2</button>
  <button >text3</button>
  <button >text4</button>
  <button demo style="display:none;">text2</button>
  <p> Display the result </p>
</div>
```

Here is script.

```
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
      var id = $(this).parent('div')[0].id;
      var answer = $( "#"+ id + " button[demo] ").text(); 
      var question = $(this).text();
      if(question.trim()==answer.trim()){
        alert('match')
     }
      else{
         alert('not match')
    }       
});
```

Please refer link for Demo purpose : [Click here for fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/budzjgm5/1/)

I think it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

To group, you could give those buttons id's too. Like button one of group one gets id1_btn1. In your jquery code you check the part of the senders id in front if the underscore. That is the id of your  group. Give your answer a fitting id and your problem should be solved.
But why don't you just give the button with the right answer an extra class? If a button is pressed, you just check if it has this special class, and if so, the answer was right. So you don't need your hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
      let answer = $(this).parents(".list-group").find("button:last").text();
      let value = $(this).text();
      if(value.trim() == answer.trim()){
       alert("matched");
      }else{
       alert("not matched");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="id1">
       <button >text1</button>
       <button >text2</button>
       <button >text3</button>
       <button >text4</button>
       <button style="display:none;">text1</button>
       <p> Display the result </p>
     </div>
     <div class="list-group" id="id2">
       <button >text1</button>
       <button >text2</button>
       <button >text3</button>
       <button >text4</button>
       <button style="display:none;">text3</button>
      <p> Display the result </p>
     </div>
```

You can use this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#id1 > button').click(function(){

$('#id1  > p').text($.trim($(this).text())==$.trim($('#id1hiddedbtn').text()))

});

$('#id2 > button').click(function(){

$('#id2  > p').text($.trim($(this).text())==$.trim($('#id2hiddedbtn').text()))

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-group" id="id1">
<button >text1</button>
 <button >text2</button>
 <button >text3</button>
 <button >answer</button>
 <button id="id1hiddedbtn" style="display:none;"> answer </button>
<p> Display the result </p>
 </div>
 <div class="list-group" id="id2">
<button >answer</button>
 <button >text2</button>
 <button >text3</button>
 <button >text4</button>
 <button id="id2hiddedbtn" style="display:none;"> answer </button>
<p> Display the result </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am generating it dynamically. so unnecessary repetition of code. right?